# Not able to set 'readonly' on text input box

Tags: html

Is there any obvious reason why this input box is editable?

```
<input id="username" name="username" class="textfield70pc" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="My username" />
```

It seems kind of pointless having to use javascript / jquery to disable this text box.

Comment: This should work: The field should be focusable, selectable, but not changeable. Can you post a online example? Are you sure there is no other functionality (e.g. some jquery stuff) interfering and re-activating fields? Is `disabled` an option?

Comment: works for me: http://jsbin.com/utivi

Comment: I've tested it this end and it seems fine... make sure your HTML is W3C valid.

Comment: Pekka, you are right. I was fooled by IE and FF when the cursor started blinking, indicating that it was editable. Setting `disabled="disabled"` solved this. To bad Ican't select your answer as the correct one :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for it to be grayed out, add the `DISABLED` attribute:

```
<input id="username" name="username" ... disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: To be valid HTML it should be:  
`<input id="username" name="username" disabled="disabled" />`